# iOS: At a specific coordinate, adding a UIView as subview of another UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have ten (x,y) coordinates values in NSInteger array. //Yet to implement

I want to add a series (10 array) of **UIView** on another bigger **UIView**.

```
[self.myBiggerView addSubview:mySmallView];
```

I am not getting how to add **mySmallView** at a specific (my coordinate array) coordinate.
Please help

Comment: mySmallView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);?

Comment: i dunno if you have this in mind but the frame of `mySmallView` should be relative to `myBiggerView`. also since you're yet to implement the coordinate array, it won't be an array of `NSInteger`s but an array of `NSNumber` objects (_just saying, if you knew all this, don't shoot me_)

Comment: @staticVoidMan: Thanks for your response, NSNumber I am using. Thankk you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either after or before

```
[self.myBiggerView addSubview:mySmallView];
```

Set the frame of your small view like this:

```
mySmallView.frame = CGRectMake(coord1,coord2,width,height);
```